# Laravel custom middleware for 2 databases

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-middleware, laravel-sanctum, multi-database

I don’t know how to create middleware for two databases tokens.

(First of all my english is not very well and I am beginner in laravel) I created a Laravel project that has two Eloquent Authenticatables that separate the database. I successfully saved tokens to personal access tokens for both databases, but I don’t know how to create middleware for those tokens. The first database (the default database) does not have any problems, but the second database does.
Note 1: I’m using Sanctum for authentication.
Note 2: The reason that I have to separate two databases is because my work requires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your own custom middleware. [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware) then inside the handle function instead of using eloquent. you may use DB queries to select another database.

Modify your `app/config/database.php` like the following.

```
<?php
return array(
    'default' => 'mysql',
    'connections' => array(
        # primary
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # secondary
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then in your `middleware`.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
 
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 
class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
       // code here
       // DB::connection('mysql')->table('yourtable');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Unfortunately, I was trying to customize the middleware on my own and was unable to achieve so because an older version of Laravel in the separate project